# MySQL - Select in same table

Tags: mysql, join

I need to use `mysql` to show users (A) that not follow B, but they (A) are followed by B. This is gonna be used to suggest connections on a social media website.

My table structure:

```
ID
FOLLOWED
FOLLOWER
```

I've tried to use 
`LEFT JOIN` 
or 
`NOT EXISTS`, but didn't work.

---

@DRapp shows me how to user `LEFT JOIN` on this query. That works. Now, how to add the users information on this query (`LEFT JOIN` + `INNER JOIN`).

Inner join need to be with follow table and user table (`INNER JOIN users ON follow.follower = user.id`)

Users`s table structure:

```
ID
Name
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? We can build on that and show you what is going wrong

Comment: Show us an example of your table. Fallowed is a boolean or a string ?

Comment: What does id do? And consider providing proper, sample data and a desired result

Comment: I'm with @Smittey - show us you've made an effort. But I will give you a tip - subquery. Good luck.

Comment: Subqueries! That's the thing.

Comment: The information which you provided is not adequate. Please update the question with all the information. This will help others in understanding what you've done and will help others in identifying where are you failing.

Answer (score 0):

Given the scenario of sample data of "YourTable"

```
ID  Follower  Followed
1   A         C
2   B         C
3   B         D
4   B         E
5   C         B
6   D         A
```

The people followed by "B" include "C", "D" and "E" users.
From that, only user "C" follows "B".  So, what you are looking for is any where no MATCH for  A/B, B/A type of combination.  So that is the basis of the LEFT-JOIN.  The WHERE clause is only querying those records based on the user "B" you are considering as the originating "follower".

```
select
      yt.Followed,
      u.name
   from
      YourTable yt
         left join YourTable yt2
            on yt.Followed = yt2.Follower
            AND yt.Follower = yt2.Followed
         JOIN Users u
            on yt.Followed = u.id
   where
          yt.Follower = 'B'
      AND yt2.Followed IS NULL
```

To get then name, notice the join is to your ORIGINAL table that was based on user "B", but NOT finding the corrresponding inverse match.  So, we are joining on the ORIGINAL record's Followed (who "B" is following) to the user table by the same ID in the user table.  Then grab the user's name to the query.

Comment: @JoãoEvandro, glad it worked... as a newbie... check out the top Help -> Tour for site etiquette and marking questions as answered so others know an item is resolved or not.  Also good to do upvotes on answers that help even on this and others that help you and you found something good out of it.

Comment: Ok. Just another answer. Now, how to INNER JOIN that query with the table USERS (eg. to show the A, B, C name)?

Comment: @JoãoEvandro, edit your original question and add the sample table structure of your "users" table and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @JoãoEvandro, revised answer to include user join condition.